# Godot indexing and keyboard both at the same time

Tags: godot

I have been trying to develop keyboard and touch indexed game, playable on PC browsers and phone. How can I index?

Tried some samples in Godot Sample menu. None of them helped. Either for keyboard or touch screen

```
func _unhandled_input(event):
    if event is InputEventScreenTouch:
        if event.pressed:
            # Down
            if !_os2own.has(event.index): # Defensively discard index if already known
                var ptr_id = _find_free_pointer_id()
                state[ptr_id] = event.position
                _os2own[event.index] = ptr_id
        else:
            # Up
            if _os2own.has(event.index): # Defensively discard index if not known
                var ptr_id = _os2own[event.index]
                state.erase(ptr_id)
                _os2own.erase(event.index)
        return true
```

Need to touching and clicking game. Both for APK and HTML

Comment: Could you expand on what you are trying to implement?

Comment: ı want to be able to use both keyboard and both touch pad and need to code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple input handling (e.g. pressed and released) you'll want to map input to actions. You can add actions via "Project Settings -> Input Map" or [InputMap](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_inputmap.html) singleton.

From the "Project Settings -> Input Map" you can map mouse, keyboard, and controller input to actions.

For touch screens you can use a [TouchScreenButton](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_touchscreenbutton.html) and set it's `action`. When pressed or released it will send that action event down the scene tree via `_input()`. TouchScreenButton hides the logic needed to write in `_input()` to handle *presses and releases*, such as: is this finger index new? which finger index moved last frame? is this finger area in bounds of input area? and more. While also having the advantage over a plain Button by also emitting an action and can have no texture as it uses a Shape for input detection.

So this creates an one-to-many relationship from actions to inputs like:

```
my_action -> left mouse button pressed,
          -> controller r1 pressed,
          -> right half of touch screen pressed,
          -> control-shift-f pressed
```

### Using the action

```
func _input(event):
    if not event.is_action('my_action'):
        return
    if event.is_action_pressed('my_action'):
        start_something()
    else:
        stop_something()
```

### Going further

Since the post specified keyboard and touch input, I only covered press and release input action mapping. However, you can map complex inputs like gestures to actions as well. You can inherit from InputEvent or any of it's subclasses to extend or create a new event. You can map the new event class to an action and then manually process input to find an event. Then you stop the propagation of the event, form the event from your new event class, and then call `Input.parse_input_event(my_new_event)` to send it down the tree.

#### Custom Action

```
# SomeLeafNode.gd

class MyEvent extends InputEvent:
    var my_custom_message = 'Hello, World'

func _ready():
    InputMap.add_action('my_event')
    InputMap.action_add_event('my_event', MyEvent.new())

func _input(event):
    # ... logic to see if event could be MyEvent
    get_tree().set_input_as_handled()
    var my_event = MyEvent.new()
    my_event.my_custom_message = 'Caught my event!'
    Input.parse_input_event(my_event)

# SomeInputHandlingGameplayNode.gd

func _input(event):
    if event.is_action('my_event'):
        print(event.my_custom_message) # prints 'Caught my event!'
```

Comment: This is brilliant after few tries, you have all set up. Thanks

Comment: I have tried this but does consume memory a bit. Those who implement can use it knowing that

Comment: @Bitdom8 I’m glad this worked for you. How much is it consuming for you? What is your implementation like?

Comment: Well, after godot 3.3 all went smoother. Thanks. Imp is exactly same as yours